# Bootstrap 4 doesnt collapse

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, richfaces

i'm getting troubles on using bootstrap 4 in a jsf - richFaces web application.
I have a template that include 2 portion of .xhtml pages 
Seems that accordions divs doesnt recognize Bootstrap classes. 
I've no console error. I had to put jQuery.noConflict() for avoid any issue with chart.js (an other tab)
and i think that could be the problem. 
I tryed in several ways without any results, can you help me?

Template.xhtml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
      xmlns:fn="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"> 
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/susy2.css" />
    <script src="../resources/js/collapse.js"></script> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/cards.css" />  
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/table.css" />    
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script> jQuery.noConflict();</script>
    <script src="../resources/js/creaGrafico.js"></script>
    <script src="../resources/js/Chart.js"></script>


    <f:view>
        <div class="content" id="portletAVCP">
        <ui:include src="/include/header.xhtml" />
    <!--    <a4j:keepAlive beanName="analisiDatiBean" ajaxOnly="true"/> -->

    <!-- <h:form styleClass="avcpForm"> -->
    <h:form styleClass="#{richSkin}">
    <rich:layout>
        <rich:layoutPanel  position="top" width="100%">
           <div class="divTitoloQuestionario">
                <h:outputText styleClass="titoloQuestionario" value="#{analisiDatiBean.questionario.datiQuestionario.titoloQuestionario}" />
           </div>
        </rich:layoutPanel>


        <rich:layoutPanel  styleclass="tabellaQuest" >
            <rich:tabPanel  binding="#{analisiDatiBean.tabPanel}" selectedTab="#{analisiDatiBean.selectedTab}" id="listaDomandaCorrente"> <!-- switchType="ajax" -->
                <c:forEach var="sezione" items="#{analisiDatiBean.sezioni}">

                    <rich:tab id="idTree_#{sezione.id.idTree}" styleClass="tabSezione" label="#{sezione.label}" action="#{analisiDatiBean.cambiaSezione}"> <!-- reRender="alberoLaterale" --> 
                        <f:param name="idSezione" value="#{sezione.id.id}"/>

                        <div class="domanda">
                        <div class="domandaSenzaBottoniera">
                            <p>
                                <ui:include src="../include/messagePage.xhtml" />
                            </p>

                                <ui:include src="../builder/componenti/listaComponenti.xhtml">
                                    <ui:param name="listaComponentiCorrente" value="#{analisiDatiBean.listComponenti}" />
                                </ui:include>

                            <!-- </p> -->
                        </div>                          
                        </div>  
                    </rich:tab>
                    <rich:tab styleClass="tabSezione" label="Analisi in dettaglio">
                        <div class="domanda">
                             <p>
                                <ui:include src="../include/messagePage.xhtml" />
                            </p>
                                <ui:include src="../builder/componenti/analisi2.xhtml">
                                    <ui:param name="listaComponentiAnalizzabili" value="#{analisiDatiBean.listComponenti}" />
                                </ui:include>
                        </div>


                    </rich:tab>
                </c:forEach>
            </rich:tabPanel>    
        </rich:layoutPanel>

        <rich:layoutPanel position="bottom">
            <p class="pager">
                <h:commandButton class="button" value="Esci"
                    action="#{analisiDatiBean.tornaAllaSelezioneQuestionari()}" >
                </h:commandButton>
            </p>                         
        </rich:layoutPanel>
    </rich:layout>

        </h:form>
        </div>
    </f:view>

</body> 
<ui:include src="/include/footer.xhtml" />
</html>
```

Include.xhtml

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
    <div id="accordion">
    <c:forEach items="#{listaComponentiCorrente}" var="componente">
            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading_#{componente.label}">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button  type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_#{componente.label}" class="btn btn-link" >
                  #{componente.label}
                </button>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_#{componente.label}" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div class="card-body">
                   <p> lista valori:
                    <c:forEach var="valori" items="#{componente.listValori}">
                    <!-- <p> lista valori: -->  <h:outputLabel  value="#{valori}" /><!--  </p> -->
                    </c:forEach>
                    </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </c:forEach>
   </div> 
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Hi, please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info especially the 'mcve' part. And sure you don't have an `h:head`? And sure it is not richfaces related but pure JSF? If so, remove all the richfaces things since they do not play a role then. If it is richfaces related, it most likely is not jsf related but pure richfaces.

Comment: thank you Kukeltje, i've changed jsf related tag to richfaces